# Subscribe to event of changing time on local system

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling

Is there a way to my C# winforms application knows when Date and time settings has changed on local computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you want to take a look at [SystemEvents.TimeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.timechanged.aspx).

```
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.TimeChanged += 
    new EventHandler(SystemEvents_TimeChanged);

void SystemEvents_TimeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // The system time was changed
}
```

From the documentation:

> Occurs when the user changes the time
>   on the system clock.

Comment: Just a word of caution: when time is changed, the event fires twice

Answer (score 2):

I think [`SystemEvents.TimeChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.timechanged.aspx) is what you are looking for.