# Handling system time change in windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, windows

I have a windows application and I want any event when user changes the time of that system on which that windows application is opened or running.

How can I get that changed time or specific time or any event of system change of time/date?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subscribe to event of changing time on local system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787299/subscribe-to-event-of-changing-time-on-local-system)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can subscribe to [SystemEvents.TimeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.timechanged.aspx) event.

To subscribe to above event, do the following:

1.Create TimeChanged EventHander.

```
    private void time_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Time Changed");  
    }
```

2.Add above event handler to `SystemEvents.TimeChanged` event.

```
 SystemEvents.TimeChanged += time_Changed;
```

Comment: How can I use that method? I am bit confused here as am new to windows app.

Comment: Yes, but make sure there is a message pump running. This won't work in a console application unless you create a message pump. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/764904/56778 for an example.

Comment: I wrote my code, but message box is not firing on change of system time... See below code. public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static event EventHandler TimeChanged;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TimeChanged += Form1_TimeChanged;
        }

        protected void Form1_TimeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

`...or any event of system change of time/date?` SystemEvents.TimeChanged will only trigger "*when the user changes the time on the system clock*".

System time changes may also occur due to system time adjustments, being initiated by the system or the user. You may use the
[GetSystemTimeAdjustment function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to capture such system time adjustments.